# Using empty boost::accumulators

Tags: c++, boost, nan, boost-accumulators

How to check an empty boost::accumulators acc or not?

For example:

```
if (acc.isEmpty())//I don't know what function here
 return 0;
else 
 return boost::accumulators::mean(acc).
```

Because if it's empty, i get NaN for boost::accumulators::mean(acc).

Comment: on some platforms the nan might be signalling (I"m not sure the standard specifies this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the accumulator [`count`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library.count):

```
if (boost::accumulators::count(acc) == 0)//I don't know what function here
 return 0;
else 
 return boost::accumulators::mean(acc);
```

Alternatively, you could simply check if it is `nan` by calling [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan):

```
 if(std::isnan(boost::accumulators::mean(acc))
    return 0;
 else
    return boost::accumulators::mean(acc);
```